# Determine the next day from a list of days

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function that takes 2 arguments. The first argument is the current day of the week (a number 1-7, for Monday - Sunday) and a second argument is an object that can have different amounts of properties and values: e.g

```
    example1 = {day1: 5, day2: 2, day3: 1, day4: 7};
    example2 = {day1: 2, day2: 4, day3: 5};
    example3 = {day1: 2, day2: 6};
```

I want to know the next day (if the current day is found the next day is the current day) in the object depending on the current day of the week.
For example: on a Saturday (currentDay = 6) the expected output of example1 would be 7, the output of example2 would be 2 and the output of example3 would be 6. The object can also be empty (then the return would be currentDay). My idea was to iterate through the object and calculate the day minus the current day so the lowest number would be the next day. If all numbers are negative we have a new week. I'm fairly new to javascript. Heres my try, but I can't get it to work properly.

```
_determineNextDay = (currentDay, days) => {
    let negativeCheck = 0;
    let nextDay = currentDay;
    let countDays = 0;
    let calc = 0;
    for (let i in days) {
        countDays++;
        calc = days[i] - currentDay;
      if (calc < 0) {
        negativeCheck++;
      };
      if (calc >= 0 && calc < nextDay) {
        nextDay = calc + currentDay;
      };
    };
    calc = 0;
    if (negativeCheck == countDays && countDays > 0) {
      for (let i in days) {
        calc = days[i] - currentDay;
        if (calc < nextDay) {
          nextDay = calc;
        };
      };
      nextDay = nextDay + currentDay;
    };
    return nextDay;
  };
```

Comment: I have a very hard time deducing the exact logic of what you're trying to do. Could you describe the problem you're solving this way in one sentence? Since it's likely we could solve this with some basic datetime maths instead of looping over the object.

Comment: The days in the object are based on user input. They are saved in this way because its easier to handle in other parts of my code. I want to know if the user picked the current day of the week and if not, which day is the next one to the current week day. For Example: The User input is Monday, Wednesday and Friday. So on a Tuesday the output would be Wednesday, but on a Thursday the output would be Friday. Sorry to confuse you, I really try to describe my problem. Would be appreciated if we could solve this with some basic datetime maths.

Comment: So the user picks a bunch of days and you want to know which of those days is the next day that will happen? Are these days actual datetimes you cast? If so, your solution is: use getTime() on each of those days. Filter away all the days that occur before the current timestamp. Of the remaining days, the one with the lowest timestamp is the next day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const find_closest_day = () => {
  const picked_days = Array
    .from( document.querySelectorAll( 'input:checked' ))
    .map( checkbox => checkbox.getAttribute( 'data-day' ))
  const current_day = new Date().getDay() || 7;
  const closest_day = picked_days.find( day => day >= current_day )
    || picked_days.sort().shift()
    || current_day;
  alert( closest_day );
};
document.querySelector( 'button' ).addEventListener( 'click', find_closest_day );
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
  <input type="checkbox" data-day="1">
  <span>Monday</span>
  </li>
  <li>
  <input type="checkbox" data-day="2">
  <span>Tuesday</span>
  </li>
  <li>
  <input type="checkbox" data-day="3">
  <span>Wednesday</span>
  </li>
  <li>
  <input type="checkbox" data-day="4">
  <span>Thursday</span>
  </li>
  <li>
  <input type="checkbox" data-day="5">
  <span>Friday</span>
  </li>
  <li>
  <input type="checkbox" data-day="6">
  <span>Saturday</span>
  </li>
  <li>
  <input type="checkbox" data-day="7">
  <span>Sunday</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<button>Closest</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Shilly, but i don't want the user to pick days every time. He has the option to pick specific days of the week for different things. For example, if he picks Wednesday, it means every Wednesday until he changes is settings. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Chris_L I have updated my answer with a solution that just returns the day of the week as requested.

Comment: To be fair, the solution posted here before by the other person was even shorter. I didn't think of using `array.find()` to do the filter and minimum in one step.

Comment: I was a little bit to quick here. In the case it's the end of the week (current_day = 7;) but the user picked, for example, Monday and Tuesday (picked_days = [1, 2];) the logically next day would be Monday, but the output is Sunday. Right?

Comment: Yes. I based myself on `The object can also be empty (then the return would be currentDay)` for that logic. Then we just have to change current_day into the lowest value of the picked days.

Comment: @Chris_L Updated again. I've changed the logic to use the `.find()` logic as per the other answer, since it's shorter. If no days are selected, it returns the current day. If only days in the past are selected, it returns the earliest day of the selected ones. If days in the future are selected, it returns the earliest day in the future. So in the end, this can be written in one long statement. :)

Comment: Thanks four you help Shilly. Your line of code is way over my head now ^_^' However, it's still not working 100% as intended. If the current day is picked, e.g. the user picked Wednesday and it's actually Wednesday, the output is not current_day but the closest next day. It looks like such a simple problem, but I was looking for a solution for several days.

Comment: I've changed day > current_day into day >= current_day. So if the current day is selected, that will always be shown. Keep in mind this also means that the user can never find a day in the future if they also select the current day as an option and it's that day when the script runs.